# Extracting Filenames from SAF content URIs

Tags: java, android, storage-access-framework

Hello my fellow stackoverflows,

I am writing an application where I implemented an Activity that handles share-intents.
So far it works fine but during testing I have got a problem with Quickoffice (Android 4.4, KitKat),
because it returns an URI from which I can´t get the filename from. I also tried sharing with other apps like Dropbox and it works there.

The exact URI I get from the Qickoffice app:

```
content://com.quickoffice.android.quickcommon.FileContentProvider/5cmeDeeatcdv8IFyu-bEr2w1jSHrvPmCzXGb_VvZulMBErE5Tmfd_5P5kckE68LaEYDVSp3q5r19%0A4sOkpYCEM_VqK6Y%3D%0A
```

This was the code I used first:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; // = "_data"
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
        cursor = cr.query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null); // <--EXCEPTION

        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.d("clixend", "Exception: " + exception);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where I received following error:

```
09-23 16:54:17.664  32331-32341/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported column: _data
        at com.google.android.apps.docs.quickoffice.FileContentProvider.query(FileContentProvider.java:78)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:857)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

After some research I figured out that Android 4.4 Kitkat introduces SAF (Storage Access Framework) which manages data different, so I tried the following Code from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html to get the name:

```
public String getNameKitkat(Uri contentUri) {
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
            .query(contentUri, null, null, null, null, null); // <--EXCEPTION
    try {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String displayName = cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));

           return displayName;
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I also receive an error code:

```
09-23 16:49:43.317  32331-32421/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: columnNames.length = 4, columnValues.size() = 2
        at android.database.MatrixCursor.addRow(MatrixCursor.java:157)
        at android.database.MatrixCursor.addRow(MatrixCursor.java:128)
        at com.google.android.apps.docs.quickoffice.FileContentProvider.query(FileContentProvider.java:95)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:857)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

If somebody knows how to get the name out of the URI I get from Quickoffice I would be very thankful.

Comment: i think it because Dropbox doesn't care about filename ... seems like this uri is only for use with contentResolver.openInputStream

Comment: This can't be because dropbox and other apps display the name oft the file during the share procedure. That means you have to get the filename somehow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I searched some more I found the answer to my question how to get the filename from the URI I get from Quickoffice.

```
public String getNameFromURI(Uri contenturi){

    String[] proj = {
            OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            OpenableColumns.SIZE
    };
    String name = null;
    int size= 0;
    Cursor metadataCursor = getContentResolver().query(contenturi,  proj, null, null, null);

    if (metadataCursor != null) {
        try {
            if (metadataCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                name = metadataCursor.getString(0);
                size = metadataCursor.getInt(1);
            }
        } finally {
            metadataCursor.close();
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

The problem was I didn´t use the proper Typ, I wanted to receive.
After using:

```
String[] proj = {
        OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
        OpenableColumns.SIZE
};
```

it worked perfectly fine.
Sorry for your waste of time.